# Findout a particular letter in a column. once found i need output of the word in a new column - PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Input
Customera, c-customerrb, b-customerc

Ouput
c-customerrb

Here Customera, c-customerrb, b-customerc is a value of a cell.
I need to find out in each cell of column "C-". If the value found. it shuould return value as "C-customerrb"

Answer (score 1):

Create a Calculated column

Column = IF(CONTAINSSTRINGEXACT(Search column,"search string"),search column,"")